# Using setdiff with cellfun giving error

Tags: matlab, cell-array, set-difference

MyCell is a 5x10 cell of string cells (file names). I want to remove one element in each 5 cells based on string matching.

If I type:

```
setdiff(MyCell{1,1}, {'Dontwant.mat'})
```

it works, I get a 9-elements cell with the remaining elements.

Now I want to do this for each 5 elements, but if my script includes:

```
MyCell=cellfun(@(x) setdiff({x},{'Dontwant.mat'}), MyCell , 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

I get the following error:

> Error using cell/setdiff>cellsetdiffR2012a (line 292) Input A of class
>   cell and input B of class cell must be cell arrays of strings, unless
>   one is a string.
>
> Error in cell/setdiff (line 84)
>       [varargout{1:nlhs}] = cellsetdiffR2012a(varargin{:});

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `{}` within `setdiff`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` that will be passed to your anonymous function is already a cell array, you don't need to wrap it in braces `{x}` so the correct version is:

```
MyCell=cellfun(@(x) setdiff(x,{'Dontwant.mat'}), MyCell , 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

`setdiff` also works if one argument is string so you can simplify it by using

```
MyCell=cellfun(@(x) setdiff(x,'Dontwant.mat'), MyCell , 'uniformoutput', 0);
```